# load json data into editorjs

Tags: javascript, database, load, editorjs

On my webpage, I have an editorjs. The user types in the information, and it is saved into my mongodb (as JSON). If I want to edit the information, I'm trying to get that information from the database and load it back into the editorjs. I've tried a couple different thing; none of which are working. This is what I have in my editorjs.js file:

```
const description = data.description; // My JSON that was saved.
console.log(description); // So far so good, console logs just what should be expected.

const editor = new EditorJS({
  holderID: 'editorjs',
  tools: {
    // toolbar configuration here
  },
  data: description // This doesn't work, however if I copy and paste
                    // the data that the console logged from earlier,
                    // it loads correctly into the editorjs
});

// My newest attempt here
editor.isReady.then(() => {
  console.log('ok'); // Works so far
  console.log(description); // Also works, logging the same information as earlier
  editor.render({
    description
  });
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried JSON.parse(description) ?

Comment: I did, and that didn't work, however I was doing it like this: const description = JSON.parse(data.description); What I just tried was having two separate lines, which worked for some reason. So now I have var description = data.description; description = JSON.parse(description); and this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I said this in the comments but i will say it here so others can see it more clearly when they come to this post. He was missing `JSON.parse()` to parse the JSON.